# wget command not found in hp-ux box, looking for alternative

Tags: hp-ux

I am using hp-ux box and want to use wget to test a url is up or down. I am getting an error wget not found, samething happened with curl command. please suggest what can i use instead of wget and curl.

Answer (score 4):

If you have perl installed with the libwww-perl distribution, you may have the [lwp-request](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/libwww-perl/bin/lwp-request) program. Usage is simple:

```
lwp-request http://acme.tld/
```

For scripting, the exit status will be zero if the URL is good and non-zero if it's bad. If you don't care about the output, just pipe it to `/dev/null`:

```
if lwp-request $url >/dev/null
then
    echo "URL is good"
else
    echo "URL is bad"
fi
```

To avoid having to actually download the file at the URL, you can have `lwp-request` use the `HEAD` method like this:

```
lwp-request -mHEAD http://acme.tld/
```